# Android on Time execute

Tags: time

I am developing an app that need time related work . like i want to execute a particular service at 9pm to 6pm, in some days like Monday and Sunday do not execute that service, kindly help me .

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the AlarmManager, where you can schedule methods

[related question] [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

I hope that helps